# Automating the creation of dataframes from subsets of an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, automation

I'm working with the kaggle New York City Airbnb Open Data which is available here:
https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data

The data contains a column of the 'neighbourhood_groups', consisting of the 5 boroughs of NYC, and 'neighbourhood', consisting of the neighbourhoods within each neighbourhood group.

I have created a subset of the Manhattan neighbourhood with the following code:

```
airbnb_manhattan = airbnb[airbnb['neighbourhood_group'] == 'Manhattan']
```

I would like to create further subsets of this dataframe by neighbourhood.  However, there are 32 neighbourhoods, so I'd like to automate the process.

This is the code that I tried:

```
manhattan_neighbourhoods = list(airbnb_manhattan['neighbourhood'].unique())

neighbourhoods = pd.DataFrame()

for n in manhattan_neighbourhoods:
    neighbourhoods[n] = pd.DataFrame(affordable_manhattan[affordable_manhattan['neighbourhood'] == manhattan_neighbourhoods[n]])
```

Which produces the following error message:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not copy into new dfs unless strictly necessary. Try to do your analysis with the full df as much as possible. Use `.groupby` as in

```
by_neigh = airbnb.groupby('neighbourhood_group')
```

Then use `.agg`, `.apply`, or `.transform` as needed. Or as a last resort you can iterate with

```
for neigh, rows in by_neigh:
```

Or get just one group with

```
by_neigh.get_group('Manhattan')
```

The advantage of all this is that underlying data is not copied intil absolutely necessary, and pandas can just view the same array with different filters and slices as needed.

Read more in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)

Comment: The dataframe contains lat and lng points of the listings.  So, for each subset by neighbourhood, I'd like to generate a scatterplot.  The data needs to be subsetted before I can send it to the plot.  I don't think I can do it with .groupby.

Comment: Yes you definitely can do that with groupby, either looping and passing each group to the charting function or using `.get_group` and passing just the one. It takes just a little overhead time to create a groupby object, but once you have it you can access as many groups as you want in virtually no time.